# Mysql Finding Difference

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a data like this

```
month | type  | passenger |
2     | 1     | 15        |
2     | 2     | 20        |
2     | 2     | 18        |
3     | 2     | 10        |
3     | 1     | 15        |
3     | 1     | 25        |
4     | 2     | 30        |
4     | 1     | 16        |
```

I want to sum passengers group by type, of two months and find the difference between two. For eg.

> SUM(passenger) as month2 where month=2 group by type
>
> SUM((passenger) as month3 where month=3 group by type

Here for month 2
type1 = 15
type2 = 38

and for month 3
type1 = 40
type2 = 10

So I want result like

> Difference
>   type1 = 25
>   type2 = 28

Is it possible to do it in one query?

Thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Comment: type2 = 28 for month 2? you mean 38 right?

Comment: yes I will correct it

Comment: now the difference will be 28... also, you want the modulos diffence ? because 15-40= -25

Comment: Did it and need to ignore modules

Answer (score 0):

I would use a conditional statement within `sum()` to sum up data for a given month only and would `group by type`:

```
select type, abs(sum(if(month=2,passenger,0))-sum(if(month=3,passenger,0))) as difference
from table
where month in (2,3)
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved It

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN month=2 THEN passenger ELSE 0 END)-
SUM(CASE WHEN month=3 THEN passenger ELSE 0 END) AS difference
from table
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to query the wanted result:

```
select p2.type, p2.m2, p3.m3, abs(p2.m2 - p3.m3) as diff
from (
    select type, sum(passenger) as m2
    from mytable
    where month = 2
    group by type
) p2 inner join (
    select type, sum(passenger) as m3
    from mytable
    where month = 3
    group by type
) p3 on (p2.type = p3.type)
;

 type | m2 | m3 | diff 
------+----+----+------
    1 | 15 | 40 |   25
    2 | 38 | 10 |   28
(2 rows)
```